# calling a method from another class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have an external class(colorCode.vb) in same project as my main form.vb. 
My objective is to send a value as argument as i call a method in the colorCode.vb class, and use the value returned by the method. I don't know if its logically possible . Here i tried this but failed.

in my colorCode.vb Class i have this codes:

```
Public Sub getValue(ByVal itemCode As Integer)

    Dim codeVal() As Integer = {9999, 3034, 3040, 3035}
    Dim colorVal As String
    For counter As Integer = 0 To codeVal.Count Step 1
        If (itemCode = codeVal(counter)) Then
            Select Case codeVal(counter)
                Case 9999
                    colorVal = "BRILLIANT WHITE EMULSION"

                Case 3034
                    colorVal = "OFF-WHITE EMULSION" 
        End Select

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

and in my main form.vb i did this

```
Private Sub descTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e 
    As System.EventArgs) Handles descTextBox.TextChanged

    Dim colorDesc As colorCode = New colorCode()
    Dim itemCode As Integer = Integer.Parse(itemCodeTextBox.Text)
    descTextBox.Text = colorDesc.getValue(itemCode)'this line triggers an error.

End Sub
```

please i need some help here. already running nuts

Comment: Use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` instead of an array of integers to store mapped integer key/string value. So  you can simply return `YourDictionary(itemCode)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Subs in vb.net do not return values. You need a Function. Instead of looping through the array you can just check if the array contains itemCode and if it does proceed with the Select Case.

Do not put your code in the text changed. It will run every time a character is entered before your user has a chance to enter the entire code. Create a button and use that. Use .TryParse to validate the input. It will return True if valid and fill in the second parameter with the number.

```
Public Class colorCode
    Public Function getValue(ByVal itemCode As Integer) As String
        Dim codeVal() As Integer = {9999, 3034, 3040, 3035}
        Dim colorVal As String = ""
        If codeVal.Contains(itemCode) Then
            Select Case itemCode
                Case 9999
                    colorVal = "BRILLIANT WHITE EMULSION"
                Case 3034
                    colorVal = "OFF-WHITE EMULSION"
                Case 3040
                    colorVal = "Blue"
                Case 3035
                    colorVal = "Green"
            End Select
        Else
            colorVal = "No matching color"
        End If
        Return colorVal
    End Function
End Class
```

And in the form...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim itemCode As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, itemCode) Then
        Dim colorDesc As colorCode = New colorCode()
        TextBox2.Text = colorDesc.getValue(itemCode)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary. Wow! i discovered i should have used Public Function (instead of Public Sub)  then a return datatype As String,

Comment: One more qxn Mary, i need the code in the textchanged. I have two textboxes ( itemcodeTextbox and itemdescTextbox. I want the itemdescTextbox value to display once it receives focus after the user has input values in the itemcodeTextbox. how can i achieve that please?

Comment: I don't quite see why the user can't click a button when he is finished entering. If you really want to use TextChanged you will need to check the `itemcodeTextbox.Text.Length = 4` before you run `getValue(itemCode)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "return" part of your method.

```
Public Function getValue(ByVal itemCode As Integer) As String
```

That's what it'll take to declare you're returning a string value, and then you actually return your vale at the end of the method.

```
    Next
    return colorVal
End Sub
```

There are other ways to do this as well as better ways to deal with your "getValue" code, but this should get you running for now. The rest of the improvements are likely a different Question, or even series of Questions. Or you could go to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) stack and get more help there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `return` statement. You should also check the value of `itemCodeTextBox.Text` to make sure it's a numeric value before you call `colorDesc.getValue` otherwise your program may crash if a non-numeric value is entered into the textbox